# How to use Workflow to detect UI created records vs. API-created

Tags: workflow

I'm seeking a means of using a Workflow Field Update to set a Checkbox value only when a Lead record is created by either the API or by Web-to-Lead. The intended use is to disqualify Leads for a PushTopic query when they are manually created by a User in the UI, but to push all other Leads.

If the IsUnreadByOwner field were accessible in Workflow Rules, that would be ideal, but unfortunately it's not available there. I'd rather not hard-code the Created By value to be those of API Users or the Default Web-to-Lead creator, nor perform this simple update with yet another trigger. Is there some other means of detecting the difference between UI vs. external record creation?

Answer (score 3):

Why not pass a flag at the time of Lead creation 'madeByRobots' and base your workflows off that?

Comment: This.   And, for the web-to-lead user, you'll need to default the field value as well.